# jquery for print function not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written the following script to print a document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function print() {
        window.print();
    }
    $(".printdoc").click(function () {
        print();
    });
 </script>
```

and I am invoking the above script by an `<asp:button../>` as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" CssClass="printdoc"/>
```

Every time I click on the button it loads the page again but the query doesn't seem to work.

When I checked the resources , I found the following console error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You also are going to have a problem with `window.print` being redefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` may collide with the built in print function. So let's call it `printPage`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printPage() {
        window.print();
    }
 </script>
```

In additional to Rahul's solution for referencing jQuery, by default `asp:Button` will postback to the server when clicked. So switch to a regular button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="printPage()" runat="server">Print</button>
```

You can leave the `runat` attribute off if you want, it's only necessary if you want to refer to it from the code behind.

---

If you really wanna use the `asp:Button`, you can do this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="printPage(); return false;"/>
```

The `return false;` will prevent the postback. But I don't see much point in using `asp:Button` for client side things.

Comment: Bingo...was almost finished editing my answer and saw your answer. Perfect! +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the reference of Jquery in your code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/sprinkle.js"></script>
```

As mason has already answered the rest, you need to create a regular button instead of `asp:button` as `asp:button` will postback to the server everytime it will be clicked.